# libreplan : Depends: tomcat6 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, tomcat

I've tried to install Libreplan, on a 14.04 server system, using the steps from [the Libreplan website](http://www.libreplan.com/download/) and [this guide](http://blog.technerdservices.com/index.php/2015/08/how-to-install-libreplan-on-ubuntu/).

I can add the PPA without problems, but when I use the `sudo apt-get install libreplan` command, I get the following error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libreplan : Depends: tomcat6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Will installing `tomcat6` solve this, and if so can it be installed alongside tomcat7? Or is there another issue here that I'm not aware of?

Edit:
I've received no error messages from `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Here's the error message generated by `sudo apt-get install libreplan`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 tomcat6 : Depends: tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.39-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and you should install  the package `tomcat6` alongside `tomcat7` to solve your problem. Both packages can be installed in parallel .

But the package should be automatically installed. I suspect that you have more problems.

For this reason run

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

and add the error messages to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libtomcat6-java 
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

This could fix your problem. You also can install tomcat6 even though there was already tomcat7 installed.